# reading linux sysfs for gpio with fgetc

Tags: c++, c, linux, embedded-linux, fgets

I write a simple program to read gpio using linux sysfs with no polling, but it seems when I want to read lower than three characters fgetc and fgets does not work correctly I wonder if this is only a bug or if I do mistaks in my code.

```
FILE* fd = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio12/value", "rw+");
if(!fd) {
    cerr << "could not open the file." << endl;
}
setbuf(fd, NULL);

while(true) {
    if(fseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_SET)) {
        cerr << "could not reposition the indicator" << endl;
    }

    char val = fgetc(fd);
    cout << val << '\r';

    cout.flush();
};
```

the above code  always return '0' even when I apply a high level voltage to gpio#12 but when I replace the fgetc and it's following line with these

```
    char str[3] = {0};
    fgets(str, 3, fd);
    cout << str[0] << 'r';
```

lines the program works correctly. on the other hand, the value file only contain one character '1' or '0' and one may think of using fgets with 2 or 1 character. in that case it does not work either. Could some one professional explain what happens there. what is wrong with the above code.
I use g++ to compile the code and my gcc version is 4.6.3-14 armhf

Answer (score 0):

You can use /bin/cat to show the contents of /sys/class/gpio/gpioXX/value files.  The contents of the file will be the ASCII character '0' or ASCII character '1' followed by a newline character '\n'.

I think you can simply go get the zeroeth byte in the file and see if it is an ASCII '0' (0x30) character or an ASCII '1' character (0x31).  Buffered I/O makes no sense in this case.

```
int fd;
char val;
int ret;

if ((ret = open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio12/value", O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
   // Fail.
   return;
}

fd = ret;

for (;;) {
   if ((ret = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET)) < 0) {
      // Fail.
      break;
   }
   if ((ret = read(fd, &val, 1)) < 0) {
      // Fail.
      break;
   }

   if ((val != 0x30) && (val != 0x31)) {
      // Whiskey tango foxtrot.
   }

   val = val - 0x30;

   fprintf(stdout, "val=%d\n", val);
   fflush(stdout);
};
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, of course I have used unbuffered stream if you mention 'setbuf(fd, NULL);' and yes the read work correctly on this case but why iso c fgetc does not works. Is that because reposition operation does not apply to fgetc or sth like this.

Comment: @AMCoded: You say your fgetc example does not work, but I tried it on an embedded ev500 PPC linux and it's A-OK.  Again, I don't think you should be worrying about the semantics of buffered I/O when operating on a sysfs virtual file that has a size of two bytes, just use open(2), lseek(2), and read(2) and perhaps focus you learning efforts on something more useful.

Comment: ok, thanks since it working in your  embeded system I wouldn't spent more time on it. I have tested the above code in raspbian for raspberry pi board. and it didn't work, so I will mark it as a bug for raspbian gcc.